# Sql left inner join + where causes (closed)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables and I want to choose the value on the left, but not on the right table. I know that is easy. **"Left Join"** and **"Where is null"** but I need a second where causes. "Column2 = 1" in right table.

[image]

Sorry about my English. I hope this image is enough to show my problem. I need to select the **T** and the **K** areas in one statement.

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as well formatted text. Also show us your current query attempt.

Comment: Have you tried this `WHERE b.column2 is null OR b.column2 = 1` ?

Comment: Without any given table structure I would say this is not possible. Your left join A->B can not return K, because it is excluded from the join. Either use union or a different query. But we can not give this without knowing some structure.

Comment: thank you for all comment. i am trying evry possible way but i can't it. Then i wirte two statement and some of python code.

Answer (score 0):

In the case when you're selecting similar sequence of columns (and these columns from both tables are compatible by type), you can use `union` operator:

```
select <some_columns>
from A
    left outer join B on ....
where B.Column2 is null

union

select <some_columns>
from B
where Column2 = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

A full join B where b.column2 is null or b.column2 = 1 and a.column is null